# ApplicationInsights CosmosDb dependecies not tracked

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a webjob created in C# hosted on App Service who is linked to Application Insights.

Following the documentation about [Dependency Tracking in Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies) and [Application Insights for .NET console applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console)
, I added the following line of code at the beginning of the program to connect ApplicationInsights and track dependecies :

```
var appInsightsKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
{
    var config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    config.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey;
    _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);

    var depModule = new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule();
    depModule.Initialize(config);
}
```

The trace are correctly tracked and I have almost all my dependencies visible in AppInsights. Unfortunatelly, I have a CosmosDb Mongodb databases in this batch and interract with it using the last version of MongoDb driver. This dependency is not tracked and visible in ApplicationInsights.

Following the documentation who say :

> Azure Cosmos DB is tracked automatically only if HTTP/HTTPS is used. TCP mode won't be captured by Application Insights.

Given the fact that I use the mongoDb connexion string, I'm in HTTPS. So why isn't it logging the mongodb dependency ?

Comment: Are you sure you're communicating with `Mongo` over `http`? Maybe I'm just a noob in Mongo but their docs seem to be clear about this `The MongoDB Wire Protocol is a simple socket-based, request-response style protocol. Clients communicate with the database server through a regular TCP/IP socket.` see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/
Could it be that ApplicationInsights docs mean the Mongo HTTP Api? In such case it's just regular http calls, see https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the MongoDb driver, all request are not automatically pushed as dependency in AppInsights.
Following [this documentation](https://admcpr.com/2017/02/09/monitoring-mongodb-with-application-insights/) and the last version of the ApplicationInsight SDK, I added the following code in my repository and it's works fine :

```
private readonly TelemetryClient _client;

public FooRepository(IMongoRepositoryConfigurationManager configurationManager, TelemetryClient telemetryClient = null)
{
    _client = telemetryClient;
    var url = new MongoUrl(configurationManager.MongoConnection);
    var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(url);

    if (_client != null)
    {
        mongoClientSettings.ClusterConfigurator = clusterConfigurator =>
        {
            clusterConfigurator.Subscribe<CommandSucceededEvent>(e =>
            {
                _client.TrackDependency("MongoDb", e.CommandName, e.Reply.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Subtract(e.Duration), e.Duration, true);
            });
            clusterConfigurator.Subscribe<CommandFailedEvent>(e =>
            {
                _client.TrackDependency("MongoDb", $"{e.CommandName} - {e.ToString()}", e.Failure.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Subtract(e.Duration), e.Duration, false);
            });
        };
    }

    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);
}
```